# Android app csv file getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: java, android, csv, arraylist

I have a csv file inside my raw folder which has multi columns, I'm able to read from the first column which seems to produce all of the data in the csv file, which is not what I want, however when trying to read the next I get :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

I tried different ways of writing the code below and I keep getting the same result, here is a snippet of the csv file:

```
OrganisationID OrganisationCode

1421            RV9HE
```

Can anyone please advise me to where I'am going wrong and why I keep getting, please?

```
Caused by:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 ?
```

I'm pulling my hair out with this, could it be the csv file has no columns and I'm just reading from the header of the csv file ?

```
private String OrganisationID;
private String OrganisationCode;

public String getOrganisationID() {
    return OrganisationID;
}

public void setOrganisationID(String organisationID) {
    OrganisationID = organisationID;
}

public String getOrganisationCode() {
    return OrganisationCode;
}

public void setOrganisationCode(String organisationCode) {
    OrganisationCode = organisationCode;
}
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] RowData = line.split(",");

            String setId = RowData[0];
            String setCode = RowData[1];

            HospitalReader cur = new HospitalReader();
            cur.setOrganisationID(setId);
            cur.setOrganisationCode(setCode);

            this.add(cur);
        }
```

Comment: How is that snippet csv content when it has no commas (,) ?? :)

Comment: What do you mean ??? this is the csv snippet before I parse it

Comment: csv stands for comma separated values, typical csv content would look like "1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"

so was just confirming if your format was fine

Comment: I understand what a CSV file mean thanks, so are you thinking then that there is no commas and that why the error ? because I added commas ??

Comment: so yeah when you said you are able to read from first column of csv, csv doesn't really have columns. It lines of text separated by "," and "\n" .. commas mark columns and "\n" or newline character marks rows. Its slightly different from xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Commas in you csv file and remove any extra lines and spaces in between

```
"OrganisationID","OrganisationCode",,,,
"1421","RV9HE",,,,
```

Or if you want to use the same file

```
OrganisationID OrganisationCode
1421            RV9HE
```

then you need to change the argument to split method

```
String[] RowData = line.split("[ ]+");
```

Comment: see the updated answer if you want to use your original file as input. You need to use Regex to split by one or more spaces

Comment: No sorry, if I put a try catch around second row cur.setOrganisationCode(RowData[1]); I catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and the display showing 2 columns instead of all the data, which is much better, but still not correct as I need to catch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code so just giving an example hoping you would be able to spot if there was an issue with your input.

Input Content (xyz.csv):

```
"OrganisationID","OrganisationCode"
"1421","RV9HE"
```

Code: Taken from https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

```
    String csvFile = "xyz.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] txt = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println(txt[0] + "....." + txt[1]);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
"OrganisationID"....."OrganisationCode"
"1421"....."RV9HE"
```

Comment: I don't get why with adding commas that I still get  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 with using the code above, also why have I been marked down as my code and layout is good ?